# How to setup eclipse cpp to generate multiple executables

Tags: c++, eclipse, build-process, eclipse-cdt

I have made a new project in a clean eclipse installation and imported a lot of source and header files into a source directory.

Some of the source files are libraries, some have a main method and are supposed to be compiled into an executable.

How can I indicate which source files are supposed to be executables? Should I make different build projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is able to generate multiple executables when you write your own makefile. Eclipse is than just performing a make all and puts all binaries in Debug or Release. Then you can run them individually.

Steps to use own makefile: 
New -> Project -> C++ -> MakeFile project